# Most Efficient Way to Delete all Records in a table if any exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to figure out what the fastest script would be to check a table if there are any records and then delete the records.

```
DELETE FROM COMPANY IF EXISTS (some sql here)
```

but is that the fastest way to do this? I need to run this from tests is why I care about performance here.

Comment: You don't need to check for records in COMPANY before deleting all records there - just perform the DELETE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TRUNCATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html)

> TRUNCATE quickly removes all rows from a set of tables. It has the same effect as an unqualified DELETE on each table, but since it does not actually scan the tables it is faster.

You can truncate multiple tables at once.